# Is it possible to compression and scaling in single command using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line, command

I used this command for Image compression:

```
"ffmpeg -hide_banner -i in.png -pix_fmt pal8 -vf dctdnoiz=4.5 -y out_2.png"
```

and this command for scaling:

```
"ffmpeg -i 1.png -vf scale=250:250 output_250x250.png"
```

I'm new to FFmpeg and I have tried my first and second command in FFmpeg.
I tried the below command.

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i in.png -pix_fmt pal8 -vf scale=250:250 dctdnoiz=4.5 -y out_2.png
```

But, It's not working and outputs this error:

```
[NULL @ 0x562190cf5140] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'dctdnoiz=4.5'
dctdnoiz=4.5: Invalid argument
```

How is it possible or how to get it to work or do I need to make two FFmpeg instance for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.png -vf "scale=250:250,dctdnoiz=4.5,format=pal8" output.png
```

- Simple filters (filters that accept 1 input and make 1 output) can be connected with a comma. See [FFmpeg Filtering Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html).
- This example uses the format filter instead of the legacy `-pix_fmt` alias so you can more easily apply pal8 wherever you want in relation to the other filters.